# What is the Python API I can use to calculate the cost of a BigQuery query?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Did any one know the how to use the Python Google Cloud BigQuery API to calculate the cost of a query?

Answer (score 6):

#### 1. Get the amount of data processed by your query

Using the Google Cloud Python SDK, you can set the `dry_run` flag.

```py
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.dry_run = True
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = client.query(
  ...
)
```

- [bigquery/docs/snippets.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/docs/snippets.py#L2052)
- [Google Cloud Docs: Issuing a query dry run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries)

#### 2. Calculate cost from `total_bytes_processed`

If you're using [on-demand pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) look at `query_job.total_bytes_processed` to see how much processed data you'd be billed for. Current cost (as of October 2019) is **$5 per TB** processed, where the first TB is free.

So, you can get the cost with something like this:

```py
cost_dollars = (query_job.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5
```

Comment: Thank you for Reply!

Do you know how to derive the cost of Dollars associated with query. 

The Big query has lot of factors for the cost calculation in the account such as Based on the Active storage,Queries (annual flat-rate), Long-term storage.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Its difficult to figure out the Dollar associated with query. Does any know python functions will do (We can write simple match query_job.total_bytes_processed/GB price per query.

Thanks,
Anand C

Comment: @Anand, most of those (especially the storage ones) don't affect the cost of a specific query.  The only one that might is if you are using flat rate pricing, but in that case, the slot usage (which is really only indirectly "pricing") is going to depend on the actual execution of the query itself.  There isn't a way to calculate it in advance.

Comment: on-demand pricing for queries is $5/TB scanned, so you can back into the math using `total_bytes_processed`. e.g. if `total_bytes_processed` is 1TB, then it'll cost you $5.

Comment: Updated answer to be more specific about how you might do this for on-demand pricing.

Comment: It might not make sense to always remove the 1 free TB, since that's not really a per-query effect.

Comment: ha, good call, I'll fix that. OP can always dry-run all his queries and load the data into BQ for analysis :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can calculate the cost directly, but you can use the dryRun parameter in the python API to get the number of bytes processed, which you can then convert to cost (at the [listed on demand price](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#pricing_summary) of $5/TB).

Something like:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.dry_run = True
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = bigquery.Client().query(
    (
        "SELECT my_column FROM my_table"
    ),
    location="US", # or wherever your data is
    job_config=job_config,
)

print("{} bytes will be processed".format(query_job.total_bytes_processed))
```

Here's a reference to the [cost estimation docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs) as well.

Comment: Is it true that when u query the line `query_job = bigquery.Client().query`, you already lost the money. Is there any way to know how many bytes before running it like working on BigQuery !

Comment: Not if you specify dry_run, @ChauLoi

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project in place, you might want to do :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bqclient = bigquery.Client(
    project='myproject',
)

query = "SQL BLA BLA SELECT etc.. " 
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.dry_run = True
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = bqclient.query(
    
    (
       query
    ),
    location="US", # or wherever your data is
    job_config=job_config,
)

cost_dollars = (query_job.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5

print(f"{query_job.total_bytes_processed} bytes will be processed , cost ~{cost_dollars}$")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from math import floor, log


def format_bytes(size):
    power = 0 if size <= 0 else floor(log(size, 1024))
    return f"{round(size / 1024 ** power, 2)} {['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][int(power)]}"

def run_bigquery(query=''):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(dry_run=True, use_query_cache=False)
    if not query:
        return []
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
    bytes_scanned = format_bytes(query_job.total_bytes_processed)

    if 'GB' in bytes_scanned or 'TB' in bytes_scanned:
        print(query)
        print(f'Alert: Query data scan costs might be higher: {bytes_scanned}')
        return []
    
    df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
    df['bytes_scanned'] = bytes_scanned
    return df.to_dict('records')
```

This is the simple logic, I generally use in my code prevent the surprise bigquery cost!